# Reference request: generalized randomness

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, computability-theory, algorithmic-randomness

There is a plethora of notions of randomness for Cantor space ($\phantom{}^\omega 2$) (Schnorr randomness, Martin-Löf randomness, weak 2-randomness, the various forms of higher randomness such as $\Delta^1_1$ randomness, and so on). See, for example, André Nies, *Computability and Randomness* (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2009), Rodney Downey and Denis Hirschfeldt, *Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity* (Berlin: Springer, 2010), or any number of other texts. And these can be extended in obvious ways to $\mathbb{R}$, $\phantom{}^\omega \omega$, and some other Polish spaces.

I have been unable, however, to find any discussions of how to extend notions of randomness to $\phantom{}^\alpha 2$ for $\alpha > \omega$, either for $\alpha$ a large countable ordinal or (more ambitiously) where $\vert \alpha \vert > \beth_1$. Any pointers to work on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There have been proposals to generalize the notion of "measure zero sets" to "higher reals", that is, to subsets of ${}^\kappa 2$ for uncountable cardinals $\kappa$, <s>typically</s>often inaccessible or weakly compact. (EDIT: sometimes also singular strong limits)

- Shelah: [A parallel to the null ideal for inaccessible $\lambda$](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/1004/), also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5799)
- Friedman-Laguzzi: [A null ideal for inaccessibles](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.11975).

Once you have the notion of a "higher null set", you can define "higher random" to mean "not an element of this or that null set" (for example: definable null set, etc)

(I prefer the adjective "higher" over "generalized", as it is more specific.)